# Reduce telemetry traffic sent from your UWP app

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-application-insights, telemetry

We have this UWP app deployed at some client machines with telemetry code.
We now want no telemetry data (if not possible reduce the traffic) to flow into app insights in azure.
By deleting the app insights resource itself, will it help in reducing the traffic through client ISP or will there be data going out of the app but just that we are not monitoring any further?

We tried Ingestion sampling, but it discards some of the telemetry that arrives from your app, at a sampling rate that you set. It doesn't reduce telemetry traffic sent from your app.

Is there a way we could handle this without changing the code?

Comment: You can try to set up [firewall rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses#outgoing-ports) to block it.

Comment: So should we block all the possible IPs from client machines (which is not practical right as we have our app deployed across The US)

Comment: ok, I'll ask help from my colleagues and see if there're some other solutions.

Comment: Thanks in advance, I really appreciate you help.

Comment: I just find a way no data can flow into app insights in azure. To do this, you can set the Daily cap to 0, but it can not reduce the traffic. And delete the app insights resource will not reduce the traffic, it's just not monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, Understood by injection sampling or using a daily cap, we can reduce the monitoring data. But I need to reduce the traffic flowing across client ISP.

Comment: As per the feedback, it seems that firewall should be the solution. Otherwise, even the app insights is deleted, the data will still go to azure(but will be rejected):(.

Comment: Thank you Ivan for you help

Comment: You're welcome. I add an answer, if it's helpful, could you please accept it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you delete the application insights resource, your app still can send telemetry data to azure server, but these data will be rejected. By this way, it cannot reduce the telemetry traffic.

The only possible way is using [firewall rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses#outgoing-ports).

And in the future, you can use some code like this to [dynamically start/stop telemetry data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/how-do-i#disable-telemetry): `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;`

Answer (score 0):

> Reduce telemetry traffic sent from your UWP app

The better way is remove telemetry code within client apps. and make new version app and publish the update with store. If you don't want to reduce telemetry with editing code, you could also disable your server api that used to revive telemetry data. And it will make client app filed when posting the data.

Comment: Thank you, But we had already done the code part, but there are some client machines working on the older versions and we have about 20k client devices as a total.
Can you please explain to me how to disable the server API, I don't see a start or stop anywhere in the app insights in Azure.

Comment: Currently, there is no such switch to disable telemetry directly, please check  Ivan Yang's comment to set up [firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses#outgoing-ports) rule to block it.